# Is it possible to add a text overlay?

Tags: skmaps

I'm trying to figure out if its possible to add a text layer to Android/IOS maps. What I'm trying to do is instead of showing an icon for some POI just write the POI title.

Answer (score 0):

The only supported "overlays" are POIs, polylines and polygons.

For your use case you might be able to hack it by using a POI with a custom view where you have text on an transparent background.